# Failed to construct Kafka consumer with keystore in S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-kafka

I have a Spark job that consumes data from a secured Kafka topic. This works when the `truststore.jks` is physically present where the job is running. However, if I point to my S3 bucket for Spark to grab the JKS file, this fails.

This is what my job looks like:

```
val kafkaReadStream = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1")
    .option("subscribe", "my_topic")
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "s3a://a-bucket/a-directory/truststore.jks"
    ...
```

To enable Spark to reach my AWS bucket I have `spark-shell` configured as below:

```
./spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell \
    --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4 \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=$AWS_SECRET_KEY
```

This is the error I get:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
  ...
  ... 57 elided
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:799)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:615)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:596)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.consumer(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anonfun$fetchTopicPartitions$1.apply(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:119)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anonfun$fetchTopicPartitions$1.apply(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:116)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anon$2$$anon$1.run(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:59)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore s3a://a-bucket/a-directory/truststore.jks of type JKS
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:153)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:140)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:65)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:88)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:713)
  ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore s3a://a-bucket/a-directory/truststore.jks of type JKS
  at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:137)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:149)
  ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore s3a://a-bucket/a-directory/truststore.jks of type JKS
  at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory$SecurityStore.load(SslFactory.java:330)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.createSSLContext(SslFactory.java:226)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:135)
  ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3a:/adlearner-featurestore-us-west-2/kafka-configs/truststore.jks (No such file or directory)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

I know for a fact that my set up to S3 is correct, since I can read a text file on the same directory as this JKS file by running this on the shell:

```
spark.read.textFile("s3a://a-bucket/a-directory/test.txt").show()
```

Comment: I doubt that `s3a://xxxx` is supposed to work for this use case. Your `spark.read.textFile("s3a://a-bucket/a-directory/test.txt")` works because Spark uses the its Hadoop machinery to build the RDD which knows to talk to S3. But this `option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "s3a://a-bucket/a-directory/truststore.jks")` is not supposed to work like this.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh how people do this? Would you suggest to use the AWS SDK and physically download the file within machine running the job?

Comment: Yes. You will need to use aws sdk to get the data of that file.

Comment: Hi @Victor , you resolve this issue by any chance?